# Dock and wing panel missing after update

Tags: wingpanel, plank

I installed Graphics drivers support.amd.com and it worked fine, after reboot elementary OS automatically installed some updates related to openGL and after that desktop seems to be broken, there is no Dock and wingpanel
[image][image]

Is it possible to rollback to the previous update?
Thanks

Comment: are you able to open terminal? use shortcut `win`+`t`, if not modified.  whats output of `apt-cache policy wingpanel plank libplank0`?

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue, just press `Alt+F2` and it will be back. Otherwise try following post:

[Loki - Dock missing](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8123/loki-dock-missing)