# Loki - Dock missing

Tags: release-loki, system, plank

Rebooted the system and the dock is missing......
Tried looking for the dock with dpkg -l and apt list but could not find it.
Tried installing the dock from the repos using apt-get install pantheon-dock but there isn't such package....

Does anyone have idea how to return it back?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried dragging your mouse along the bottom/sides of your screen, in case it is set to auto-hide?

If you still have your menu bar, go to `Applications > System Settings > Desktop > Dock` to change its settings. If it isn't set to disappear, try toggling it hidden and unhidden to see if it comes back.

[image: Desktop > Dock]

If it isn't back, let's check if it's running (the dock's process name is `plank`) with a command that shows all running processes, filtered for all lines with "plank" (open Terminal from Applications):

**`ps cax | grep plank`**

If `plank` isn't running, run the command **`plank`**, and let us know what you see? You shouldn't have to install the dock (as in the other answer) because it comes with the operating system (unless for some reason it has been uninstalled).

Answer (score 0):

The Pantheon shell is the main desktop component of the Elementary project.

It is deeply integrated with other applications like the dock called Plank , the top panel Wingpanel , application launcher Slingshot and comes with its own window manager Gala, which is based on Mutter .

If you're trying to install the dock you should try:

```
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install plank
```

Comment: Have the same issue. After reboot dock disapier. sudo apt update sudo apt install plank do not change any. any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try **scrolling your window down**.... that was my problem!  Look on the right side of screen to see if you have a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reduce the resolution of the screen to get it to come back. Scrolling didn't help.

Comment: Please use **comment** if you are not posting a direct solution to the problem of original poster.